# A design problem about interfaces and inheritance in C#.Net

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, interface

I'm going through a really hard time finding the answer to the question below, about inheritance and OOP. Can anyone please help?

**Here is the question :**

Let's assume that I have a class named **`ServiceManager`** inside an assembly named `KioskFramework`, which implements 2 different interfaces named **`IServiceManager`** and **`IServiceProvider`**.

```
public interface IServiceManager
{
    string SerialNumber { get; }
    string Description { get; set; }

    int DoFoo(IServiceManager instance, int a, int b);
}

public interface IServiceProvider
{
    void DoSomethingRESTRICTED();
}

class ServiceManager : IServiceManager, IServiceProvider
{
    public void DoSomethingRESTRICTED();

    …  // some other properties and methods...

    public string SerialNumber { get { … } }

    public string Description { get { … } set { … } }

    public int DoFoo(int a, int b)
    {
       …
    }
}
```

I have another class named **`MonitoringService`** inside an assembly named `KioskFramework.MonitoringService`, which uses certain properties of `ServiceManager` class (The ones that are defined in the `IServiceManager`).

```
class MonitoringService
{
    …  // some other properties and methods...

    public int DoBar(IServiceManager instance, int a, int b)
    {
       // an example to show that I need access to ServiceManager's properties
       return instance.SerialNumber.Length + 
              instance.Description.Length + 
              instance.DooFoo(a, b);
    }
}
```

All I want to do is, that I want to be able to use that certain properties in `MonitoringService`, but no other class or assembly (such as `ControllingService` inside `KioskFramework.ControllingService`), could access that properties.

```
class ControllingService
{
    public void DoSomethingElse(IServiceProvider instance)
    {
        // this method should not have access to the IServiceManager's 
        // properties and methods, even if it has an instance of
        // IServiceProvider, or even if it has referenced the assembly 
        // containing IServiceManager interface
    }
}
```

Is it possible? How? Is there a design pattern for solving this?

Maybe I'm thinking in a wrong manner or way, but my goal is to restrict certain members of a class to only be seen/used in certain assemblies not all of them.

edit : After Mark Cidade's answer, I edited this post, to say that I don't want to expose other internal members and classes of "KioskFramework" assembly to "KioskFramework.MonitoringService" assembly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if I don't want to expose all of the other internals? Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mark the interface as `internal` and apply an [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute to the assembly:

From KioskFramework.dll:

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("KioskFramework.MonitoringService")]
```

Comment: This was my first thought ...I wish there was a way to do this, though, directly on an interface.

Comment: so doesn't it matter that they are in two different assemblies ? Does it require "KioskFramework.MonitoringService" to be strongly named? let me tell you something. I don't want any other internal classes and members of "KioskFramework" to be visible to the "KioskFramework.MonitoringService". What about that?

Comment: It doesn't have to be strongly named. Unfortunately, all other internal classes will have to be visible to KioskFramework.MonitoringService. You cannot get more specific here.

Comment: @Mark Cidade : Are you sure that there is no workaround or design pattern to do this?

Comment: None that I think would be worthwhile. For example, you could make internals visible to an intermediate assembly and only expose from that assembly what you want, but I don't see that as a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your goal is - so some general pointers:

- you can make those interfaces `internal` and define which assembly is allowed to see those members `assembly: InternalsVisibleTo`
- you can make the members `protected` and access them via Reflection